# TLS Enabled dgraph server using c# StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Empty update" grpc exception

Tags: c#, grpc, dgraph

I  am  trying  to  connect  **tls  enabled  dgraph server** using  c#  .net   for  that  I  have  written  below  console  application

```
class DGraphClient
    {
        public IDgraphClient GetDgraphClient()
        {
            
            GraphSchemaIOConnection ConnectionConfig1 = new GraphSchemaIOConnection();
            ConnectionConfig1.Endpoint = "testdgraph.abc.tech:9080";
            DgraphInstance GSioDgraph = new DgraphInstance();
            DgraphCertificates certificates = new DgraphCertificates();
            certificates.CaCert = "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";
            certificates.ClientCert = "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCk1JSURWVENDQWoyZ0F3SUJBZ0lJS2Y3WjVYVlVIVjh3RFFZSktvWklodmNOQVFFTEJRQXdSakVhTUJnR0ExVUUKQ2hNUlJHZHlZWEJvSUV4aFluTXNJRWx1WXk0eEZ6QVZCZ05WQkFNVERrUm5jbUZ3YUNCU2IyOTBJRU5CTVE4dwpEUVlEVlFRRkV3WXhPVFk0TXpZd0hoY05NakV3TWpJeU1EWXpORFU1V2hjTk1qWXdNakl6TURZek5EVTVXakJGCk1Sb3dHQVlEVlFRS0V4RkVaM0poY0dnZ1RHRmljeXdnU1c1akxqRVdNQlFHQTFVRUF4TU5kbWx6ZFhKeFlXUm4KY21Gd2FERVBNQTBHQTFVRUJSTUdNamxtWldRNU1JSUJJakFOQmdrcWhraUc5dzBCQVFFRkFBT0NBUThBTUlJQgpDZ0tDQVFFQXF1QU04ZnlhY3l2QW42VDF2TTNsRWYrYm9QendRdVlBTW5zaFNmNjFuZVhFVTNlZ3l5cmFLSVg1CjNrSkhIV0JqSGE1T2lNUG1ib3pWT2phUldlZGVXZDdTWmozb0IwV3NEd3YzTHhuN0dPUThHQU5UU3VTMURadFYKczBSMkhIamJUM0I1WHRHeXdNVTFORHkwcTZDNXdVT1NOSk85cWhKOW4wMUwrK3ltT3RYd3JCbUhlaVVhd21vRAp2c21mWFlUREJiUC93V0lYeW5vYkd5N3R6cEtteWRmOHErcm0zd0VKQ3FTNGNEVHlwVU0rdWZIVElPYXZXQWE0CnpyUXZ0Mk11bVRiclJSWlRZUVZmdU9jbkduQ3pSS0hjQ2RJWWdFcTl3Zmx0WjRZQjAydUtYZHY2Tkw5aGJrRXYKUmozNlZUMithaG5CS2FZM1l4d0xOVGNqWWxqeXlRSURBUUFCbzBnd1JqQU9CZ05WSFE4QkFmOEVCQU1DQjRBdwpFd1lEVlIwbEJBd3dDZ1lJS3dZQkJRVUhBd0l3SHdZRFZSMGpCQmd3Rm9BVTBaRlBXOFVnamR0K2s5czBxdk9BCkNrTkVpbUl3RFFZSktvWklodmNOQVFFTEJRQURnZ0VCQUFrYWprLzNmMUo2bDBVZWZPM0ozNEpYOGszMTM4N1oKY1BZaWt1Z1A3M2wwT3dnc2oxY3VHODh3UXczREdDN3NPNlVQU0lzQ2ZHdXlVVzJmZG1QSFN5V3hxbGFGTnN2Zwo3WithVE92aHBYNGVuYTNUcE9lb0FKdUlXOVRjendLZjdBbWo2VEY1MjNaQWtkOVhhcTZMaVVwR0QzdFdhajgxCmRBK3dRVTgvaE5tZ29GR2lhVmFqYm9wVFU0K0hvTG9HWExuTTY3dU5TdGJEQ05uVlluZExDTHpDM1BORUtEYVAKdC9kMEQvczB6L1lnMi9ZaEFlMzV6WTIzNytFbkZXMCsrbG5wUEtZNFFuY1ozL3ZYN1lhYTlRejZKSFgxOG9oUwpJbVVuUEtsMzlJT21ocEJNckdCK2JxRTRTMFM1eXB3NUl6WUtMLzVsRnVtZVZoSVFoLzVmdHZRPQotLS0tLUVORCBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tCg";
            certificates.ClientKey = "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";
            GSioDgraph.Certificates = certificates;
            GSioDgraph.Address = "testdgraph.abc.tech:9080";
            if (ConnectionConfig1.Endpoint.Equals("localhost"))
            {
                var client = DgraphDotNet.Clients.NewDgraphClient();
                client.Connect("");
                return client;
            }
            else
            {
                var client = DgraphDotNet.Clients.NewDgraphClient();

                var caCert = GSioDgraph.Certificates.CaCert;
                var clientCert = GSioDgraph.Certificates.ClientCert;
                var clientKey = GSioDgraph.Certificates.ClientKey;
                var tls = new SslCredentials(caCert, new KeyCertificatePair(clientCert, clientKey));

                client.Connect(GSioDgraph.Address, tls);



                //   var  result =  client.CheckVersion();


                return client;
            }
        }
```

and  calling check  version  using  below  code

```
 DGraphClient dc = new DGraphClient();
            try
            {
                var dgraphClient = dc.GetDgraphClient();


               
                var result1 = await dgraphClient.CheckVersion();

                if (result1.IsSuccess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Dgraph version {Version}", result1.Value);

                }


                var res = await dgraphClient.Query(query);//.NewTransaction().Query(query);
                if (res.IsFailed)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR THROWING");
                }
                result = res.Value;
                await dgraphClient.NewTransaction().Commit();
              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;

            }
```

after  instanciate  client  I  am  just  checking  server  version  to make  sure  its  connected  but  failed with   grpc  `{Result: IsSuccess='False', Reasons='ExceptionalError with Message='Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Empty update")', Exception='Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="Empty update")\r\n   at DgraphDotNet.GRPCConnection.CheckVersion()\r\n   at DgraphDotNet.DgraphClient.CheckVersion()'', }`

[image]

Comment: is  there  any refrance  for  c#  dgraph  tls

Comment: I don't think Grpc itself ever generates an error with status code Unavailable and detail message "Empty update".  From what you described, the gRPC connection was actually successful and the RPC on the server side actually got invoked, but the server side handler returned an error (but the application code did that, not grpc itself). I think you need to consult Dgraph source code / documentation to see why the call is failing.